# Custom Cell Textfield index changing on Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in a custom cell. Once I entered the value in first and second cells and when I scroll the `UITableView` textfield index are changing (first cell value changing to last cell). Can any one help me to resolve my issue?

Here is my code:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellID";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {        
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] init]; // or your custom initialization
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

cell.txt_TCelltext.tag=indexPath.row;
cell.txt_TCelltext.placeholder=@"0.00";

[cell.txt_TCelltext setDelegate:self];
```

[image]

Comment: Please try after removing this line: cell.txt_TCelltext.tag=indexPath.row;

Comment: Store your value in datasource, and use it using indexPath, otherwise values will interchange due to reuse of cell.

Comment: You need to understand how reusable cells work. As you are using reusable cell, the cell which goes out of view is reused for the incoming cell. Therefore the `txt_TCelltext` gets data in addition to that it already has because row number is changing for the row that is in the view right now.

Comment: @Krishna: how can i overcome this isuue

Comment: @AjayGabani: i have done which u suggested but am getting same issue

Comment: @iphonic: can i please paste some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write below code in Viewdidload and cell for row at index path.

```
arrCells = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i < [[dic_demo objectForKey:@"Demo"] count]; i++) {
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    [arrCells addObject:cell];

}-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [arrCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

It is because of cell reuse. Try to populate the `UITextField` data from a dictionary (or) array. Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLocal
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Your Code

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.tag = indexPath.row;

    if ([myTextFieldDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)textField.tag]])
    {
        textField.text = [[myTextFieldDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)textField.tag]];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [myTextFieldDictionary setValue:textField.text
                             forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)textField.tag]];    
}
```

Comment: First cell value is printing in last cell

Comment: Edited my answer try it

Comment: @ user007007:Am getting same issue please share u mail i will send my demo source to u..you can check with that

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is newly created, you assign a placeholder/ text to text filed. **But if the same cell is reused and incase for the reused cell you didn't assign the placeholder/ text to the textfield from the data source of the current index path than the text filed will show the data for previous index path at which the cell was newly created**. So to resolve your issue you need to assign the text to the text field based on the text for the current index path irrespective of the cell is newly created or reused.

To resolve this issue you have two options-

1) update the content of reusable cells text field with the data of the text field for current index path

2) in case of reusable cell release previous text field and create a new one, initialize with the data for the present row.

The 2nd approach involves some overhead, so I would suggest you to resolve your issue with 1st approach.

**Sample code using 1st approach-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UITextField *textField = nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }

    // assign placeholder text to text field
    [cell.textFiled setPlaceholder:[textFiledTextsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

**Sample code using 2nd approach-**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UITextField *textField = nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }

    textField = [[cell contentView] viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    if(textField ! = nil)
          [textField removeFRomSuperView];

    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // customize text filed

    // assign placeholder text to text field
    [textFiled setPlaceholder:[textFiledTextsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [textField setTag:indexPath.row]; // set tag on text field

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:textField];

    [textField release];

    return cell;
}
```

**Note**: The above sample code is just a rough idea, please use the above source/ customize it as per your requirements.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, i have updated my answer with the sample code showing both the approaches.

Comment: @ Sanjay Mohnani: i tried but it was not worked for me.if u dont mind i have created demo project can i sent to ur mail can u please look it .am new to ios development. my requrement is i need to get user entered data in button action while doing that am getting above issue.

Comment: Can u please share ur mail id please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75909/discussion-between-sanjay-mohnani-and-rakesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableCellID"; 
in place of this line 
use NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell_%d_%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

Comment: it is not good approach because it create new cell every time and take to much memory

Comment: You are right but it depends on requirement if you are having simple text based cells you can go for it. Sometimes you should maintain trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakPoint in the function below and you can see it gets called each time a cell becomes visible and hence your code inside that function resets the text in the textField. If something has struck you, don't wait! you can solve it with your own code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```